# Storing and printing an exception with traceback?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a python3 program I have a certain `try...except` block where I store exceptions that occur in a certain method into a `list` of exceptions that have occurred. A simplified version looks like this:

```
def the_method(iterable):
   errors = []
   for i in iterable:
       try:
           something(i)
        except Exception as e:
            errors.append(e)
   return errors
```

**After** the method returns I want to print the errors in the console. How can I print the exceptions with traceback and the usual *uncaught exception* formatting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module. Note that the interface is ancient, so it doesn't know to use `type(exc)` and `exc.__traceback__`; you'll have to extract those yourself:

```
for exc in errors:
    traceback.print_exception(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
```

---

Also, be aware that Python has a very strange way of building tracebacks, where an entry for a stack frame is added to the traceback when an exception propagates into that stack frame, rather than building the traceback all at once when the exception is created or raised.

This means that an exception's traceback stops at the point where it stopped propagating. When your `the_method` catches an exception, the exception's traceback will stop at `the_method`.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions have attributes, just like other objects in Python. You may want to explore the attributes of your exceptions. Consider the following example:

```
>>> try:
    import some_junk_that_doesnt_exist
except Exception as error:
    print(dir(error))


['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', '_not_found', 'args', 'msg', 'name', 'path', 'with_traceback']
```

This means that for each exception in your list, you can access the exception's attribute. Thus, you can do the following:

```
for e in err:
    print(e.args)
    print(e.name)
    print(e.msg)
```

One thing that occurs to me, though, is that the following line shouldn't really append more than one exception to your errors list:

```
except Exception as e:
     errors.append(e)
```

Someone else will know better than I would, but isn't Exception *always* going to be one thing here (unless you're capturing multiple specific exceptions)?

Comment: Ok... but how do I print the exception with traceback like uncaught exception are printed?

Comment: `e.with_traceback` is a method. It sets the traceback.

Comment: Sounds like you want some more. You probably want `sys.exc_info()`. See here for examples: http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/traceback.html

Comment: ah. I have never used with_traceback. I have only ever used `.msg` for processing them. I removed that to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Is it work with `print` command, like

```
def the_method(iterable):
   errors = []
   for i in iterable:
       try:
           something(i)
        except Exception as e:
            errors.append(e)
   return errors

err = the_method(iterable)
for e in err:
    print e()
```

Comment: No. That only prints the first part of the exception. It doesn't print the type of the exception or the traceback like the way uncaught exceptions are printed.

Comment: to be fair that does print **an** exception the way, it's just that the exception that is printed is not `e`.